# how to MAKE ruby print all appropriate brackets in a 2D array

Tags: ruby

I see all sorts of advice about getting rid of the brackets, but as I perform my beginning ruby lessons, I want to see if I'm creating a 2-D array correctly.

Right now I'm limited to

```
puts my_2D_array[0]
puts my_2D_array[1] #etc
```

but I want to see

```
[ [6,6,3] , [7,4,7] , [4,7,4] ]
```

instead of what I'm getting, which is

```
663747474
```

What's the trick? And I'm definitely dealing with an array - not a string...

Comment: astounding work - thanks!

Comment: Actually, if you use ruby v1.9+ it should work for you just fine with `puts`.  The behavior displayed is only true up to v1.8.7

Comment: Using `p my_2d_array` will show the brackets as well as using `.inspect`

Answer (score 2):

`p array` will give you output you've asked for:

[[6,6,3] , [7,4,7] , [4,7,4]]

Want each row on a separate line?  Then use:

`array.each {|e| p e}`

to get:

```
[6,6,3]
[7,4,7]
[4,7,4]
```

You could add a method to the Array class:

```
class Array
  def ppa # 'pretty-print array'
    self.each {|e| p e} # or just 'each {|e| p e}' 
  end
end
```

that wold allow you to write

```
array.ppa
```

and get the same three-line output. (You could use `puts` and `inspect` instead of `p`.) Think you might use this often?  Then put this code in a file called, say, 'array_print.rb' and add `'require array_print'` to the beginning of your '.rb' code file.  Each time you run your program, the statements in `array_print.rb` will be executed, making the `Array` method `ppr` available to you.

Let's not stop there! Suppose you also wanted nicely-formatted output for three-dimensional arrays, hashes, hashes of arrays, and so on.  You could elaborate on the approach I've described above, but why reinvent the wheel?  There are several excellent Ruby gems available that take care of all of this for you.  One popular one is "awesome print".  After having installed this gem, all you need do is add `require 'awesome_print'` in your code file.  You can then use its `ap` method to format your output.  (See [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/) for instructions on how to install gems. It's easy).

To get a taste of what awesome print does, suppose that instead of the array above you wanted to display this hash:

```
hash = {"cat"=>["mice", "birds"], "dog"=>["master",["kids", "moms"]]}
```

By executing `ap hash`, you'd get this:

```
{
    "cat" => [
        [0] "mice",
        [1] "birds"
    ],
    "dog" => [
        [0] "master",
        [1] [
            [0] "kids",
            [1] "moms"
        ]
    ]
}
```